# How to use two different method with the same "name" from two different gems on the same rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, carrierwave, delayed-paperclip, carrierwave-backgrounder

The app (rails 4.2.7) i'm working on uses both `carrierwave` and `paperclip` for uploading image for two different fields on the same data model `User` (schema below).

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "first_name",             limit: 255
  t.string   "last_name",              limit: 255
  t.string   "avatar_file_name",       limit: 255
  t.string   "avatar_content_type",    limit: 255
  t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
  t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  t.string   "cv_file"
end
```

The `avatar` field is a **paperclip** object and `cv_file` is a **carrierwave** uploader.

Now, for background processing of `cv_file` field, i'm using  [carrierwave_backgrounder](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder) gem and for `avatar` field i'm using [delayed_paperclip](https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/) gem.

Both of these gems exposes `process_in_background` to process the image upload to background. So my User model looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # carrierwave
  mount_uploader :cv_file, CvFileUploader
  process_in_background :cv_file

  # paperclip
  has_attached_file :avatar, 
                    :default_url => "default-avatar.png",
                    :styles => {
                      :thumb => ['100x100#', :jpg, :quality => 80]
                    }
  process_in_background :avatar, processing_image_url: "default-avatar.png"

  # ...

end
```

I'm getting this error while trying to access any page on the app.

> undefined method `remove_avatar?' for
>
> ## Did you mean? remove_cv_file?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwhile to simply fork DelayedPaperclip and alter the name.  Beyond that, you could potentially attempt to extend DelayedPaperclip and alias the method:

`module AliasDelayedPaperclip
  extend DelayedPaperclip
  alias_method :paperclip_process_in_background, :process_in_background
end`

I haven't tested this, and it likely requires a bit of modification to actually work, but it's at least a suggestion of a path you could pursue.